# How to complete the file download and "save as" in Internet Explorer by VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to replace a document that I do the download everyday. But I don't know what I need to do after I click the download button. I need to save the document with a specific name in my documents

follow the code:

```
Dim IE As Object
    Dim n, Period1, Period2 As Double



    'retorna o internet explorer-return the correct period
    Period1 = "201612"
    Period2 = "201612"

    'abre o internet explorer
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate "http://www2.susep.gov.br/menuestatistica/SES/principal.aspx"
    IE.Visible = True

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    'seleciona as operações desejadas
    IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_edSelProd").SelectedIndex = "8"
    IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnConsultar").Click

    'seleciona o periodo
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    Set ieDoc = IE.document
        ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_edInicioPer").Value = Period1
        ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_edFimPer").Value = Period2

    'seleciona as empresas
    IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_edEmpresas").SelectedIndex = "0"

    ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1").Click

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried finding other solutions of directly saving the file using the command but it seems you need to play around with the registry entries which is not recommended. So I did it in a below manner

```html
IE.document.getElementById("downXls").Click
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:7"))
  
  CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys "%s"
  
  Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
  IE.Quit
  
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    FSO.MoveFile Source:=sfolder & "ValueResearch-Stocks-" & vert & "-" & dateval & ".xls", Destination:=DestinFileName
    FSO.MoveFile Source:=sfolder & "ValueResearch-Stocks-" & vert & "-" & dateval & ".xlsx", Destination:=DestinFileName
```

So here you need to define the paths in variable and then you just need to move the downloaded files to a desired location